# mobile browsers ignore iframe height

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile

I have defined height for iframe but mobile browsers ignore height (except firefox). On desktop browsers is not problem. It also ignore my main div. Iframe is in main div. I tried:

```
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

it do not help.

Iframe:

```
 <div class="main">
<iframe id="webmaster_frame_id" name="webmaster_frame_name" src="http://lshunter.net/ls/index.php?option=com_lsh&view=lsh&layout=webmaster&tmpl=component&sections=1&font_type=Times New Roman&font_size=11px&start_time_eventtitle_font_size=12px&tvname_font_size=12px&tz_name_font_size=12px" width="790" height="600" scrolling="auto" align="top" frameborder="0">Your browser does not support frames, so you will not be able to view this page.</iframe>
   </div>
```

main div css:

```
.main {
    height: 1150px;
    width:100%; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: -66px;
    opacity: 0.83;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px; 
}
```

This is how it looks on mobile browser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The height is too high for a mobile browser... If you want that the iframe works correctly, I have two solutions for you :

1. Definit a `min-height` in the css code for `.main` code.
2. Create a mobile version of the code.

For the second solution, there is an example :

```
/* mobile CSS */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    .main {
         height: 480px;
     }
}
```

If you want additional information, check here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

An example of Responsive Web Design : [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)